# How to use Java properties file to define objects and set the properties for the object?

Tags: java, properties, configuration

I am developing a Java program that retrieves data from various sources, manipulates the data and then sends the data to various destinations. I need to allow the user to define in a properties file the data sources, the data destinations and the modules used within the program to process the data.

I would envisage the properties file looking something like the following...

```
dataFlow1 = dataProcessorTypeA
dataFlow1.source = mySource1
dataFlow1.destination = myDestination1
dataFlow2 = dataProcessorTypeA
dataFlow2.source = mySource2
dataFlow2.destination = myDestination2
dataFlow3 = dataProcessorTypeB
dataFlow3.source = mySource3
dataFlow3.successDestination = mySuccessDestination3
dataFlow3.failureDestination = myFailureDestination3
...
dataFlow99 = dataProcessorTypeZ
```

The properties associated with each data flow will be dependent upon the module selected. So in the example above "dataProcessorTypeA" needs the "source" and "destination" properties to be set, whereas "dataProcessorTypeB" needs the "source", "successDestination" and "failureDestination" properties to be set. In the example "dataProcessorTypeA", "dataProcessorTypeB", and "dataProcessorTypeZ" would be classes within the program.

I have used properties files in the past to do simple "property=value" type configuration but I don't understand how this type of configuration can be achieved or what words I should use to search on Google to look for similar examples of what I'm trying to achieve. I also want to avoid hardcoding lots of logic into the program read the properties file as new modules may be added in the future. I'm assuming this will be similar to the way JavaBeans are configured with getters and setters.

What I want to achieve is similar to the way a user can configure Apache log4j to use multiple appenders by setting the following in the log4j properties file...

```
log4j.appender.ca=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.ca.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rfa=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rfa.File=example.log
```

I've looked through the PropertyGetter.java file in log4j and I can see that it makes use of reflections and introspection however I don't have a sufficiently deep understanding of the concepts to understand what's going on.

What I don't understand is how "log4j.appender.ca" can be created as an object, configured to use org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender and then how log4j knows to look for "log4j.appender.ca" when processing log messages. My question isn't really related to log4j but I'm using to illustrate the type of type configuration I'm looking to achieve in my own program.

Apache Shiro also provides a similar mechanism allowing the user to customise how the framework operates. I've looked through the ReflectionBuilder.java file in Shiro and can see that the Commons-BeanUtils library is being used, but again I'm somewhat out of my depth in understand what's happening within the code.

So in summary my question is can anyone provide me with a better understand of how frameworks such as log4j and Shiro allow for this type of configuration to be performed or give me some pointers in terms of what I should be searching for please?

Comment: Have a look at [`Properties#load()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html), and use with [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class.

With `Class.forName()` you can find a class given its full qualified name.

Answer (score 0):

No need for framework: use StringTokenizer(propertyname, ".") then each token represents one level of the nested map, except the last/leaf is the value.

This is handled by

```
Map<String,Map<String,..>>
```

So "dataflow1" is a key in first level map, with values "source" and "destination" at level 2, and then leaf/data values of "source1" and "destination1"

Comment: And how deep do you want to nest your maps? You can use a single `Map<String, String>` or just `Properties`.